# how to use sed, awk to print only the path with specific word?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a text file looking like this:

```
ErrorLog "|/usr/local/apache2/bin/rotatelogs /var/log/apache/error_log.%Y-%m 200M"

ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/error_log"
```

I need filter only the path with the word error_log.
I need the output as:

```
/var/log/apache2/error_log.%Y-%m
```

Or

```
/var/log/apache2/error_log
```

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Edit your Q to show sample inputs/outputs and code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Comment: should possible double quotes be truncated on each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` will do

```
$ grep -o '\S*error_log\S*' file

/var/log/apache/error_log.%Y-%m
"/var/log/apache2/error_log"
```

if you want to pull them up to the same line and get rid of the quotes pipe to

`... | tr -d '"' | xargs`

Answer (score 1):

With **`grep`**:

```
grep -o '[^[:space:]]*\<error_log\>[^[:space:]]*' file
```

- `[^[:space:]]*` - match non-whitespace character(s)
- `\<` and `\>` - are word boundaries

---

Example output:

```
/var/log/apache/error_log.%Y-%m
"/var/log/apache2/error_log"
```

Comment: Your example output for the second line has quotes and the example in the OP doesn't have the quotes. Not sure if it matters to the OP but though I'd mention it.

Comment: @user3439894, comment added under the question